# LocomotiveCMS theme files 404 after a while

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, locomotivecms

I'm hosting Locomotive CMS on Heroku, and after a while my uploaded theme files will just be blank. I get a 404 response and the actual files in the admin backend are blank.

Anyone had this issue previously?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has a read-only filesystem. Uploaded files may be stored temporarily but they will be periodically cleaned-out. It sounds like this may be happening.

Make sure you've configured Locomotive to use your Amazon S3 credentials, as outlined on this page:
http://doc.locomotivecms.com/installation/heroku